# I need some German middle words p and b minimal pairs

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

The letters p and b should be in the middle of the words, and please not like this: "tribe" and "tripe", because they pronounced here as the last sound.

Comment: But Why Though?

Comment: It's obviously not a good idea to ask for English words on GSE. German obviously is acceptable, but a bit of a background on the why's and what's would certainly be helpful.

Comment: I reposed this interesting question here, where it had a very good answer: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/german-minimal-pairs-with-non-initial-p-vs-b.3827439/#post-19554778

Comment: @fdb: that is a great answer that also made me understand the question better. Could you include the link and a short comprehensible summary in your answer?

Comment: Thank you fdb for give me some words and a historical view about this.
Answering to the question of why i ask about this: my native language is Arabic, it is one of few Languages that does not have the P sound at all, that's why i need some minimal pair to practice my pronunciation.
i'm fine actually with the aspirated P, but not with the unaspirated P, and that's why i asked for middle words pairs.
And it's very very difficult for me to distinguish between b and p by hearing, especially when the p unaspirated.

Comment: @fdb: "In another (inferior) forum", I see, I see...

Comment: Something like „Alpen“/„Alben“?

Comment: @Axel: yes exactly.

Answer (score 3):

*Oper* (meaning: an opera) and *Ober* (a waiter).

Answer (score 2):

After a while of thinking the only true minimal pair I can find is:

*hupen*<sup>[inf. of *hupen*, "to honk"]</sup> | *huben*<sup>[1st./3rd. pers. pl. of *heben*, "to lift"]</sup>

Comment: I think quite a few others have been listed on this page.

Answer (score 2):

Minimal pairs are seldom. There is a strong tendency that long vowels be followed by a lenis consonant, and an even stronger tendency that short vowels be followed by a fortis consonant, as in the following words:

- sieben (long vowel + lenis /b/)
- Sippen (short vowel + fortis /p/)

Out of the four possible combinations of long/short vowels and fortis/lenis, the combination of a short vowel and a lenis consonant is the rarest one. A possible minimal pair might be the following:

- schlabber (from *schlabbern)* – schlapper (from *schlapp)*

Answer (score 0):

A German example: Gruppe / Grube

Another: Raupen / rauben

Comment: Staupe, (im) Staube. Lappen, laben. Rappen, Raben, ... ne jetzt wird's langweilig :-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, Gruppe/Grube. Lappen/laben, Rappen/Raben are not minimal pairs, because the quantity of the first vowel is different.

Comment: Exactly, even _Liebe:Lippe_ would count otherwise.